# Calculating average using a Histogram metric

Tags: histogram, prometheus, grafana

I am generating a Histogram using a prometheus client. The metric name is `retrieve_stripe_subscription_latency_ms`. Since Histogram generates additional metrics with suffixes `_sum` and `_count`, can I calculate the average using the below query in Grafana?

`sum(retrieve_stripe_subscription_latency_ms_sum)/sum(retrieve_stripe_subscription_latency_ms_count)`

Answer (score 10):

I think [official Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/#count-and-sum-of-observations) address this. Having your metric name:

> To calculate the average [...put here a metric meaning...] during the last 5 minutes from a histogram or summary called `retrieve_stripe_subscription_latency_ms`, use the following expression:
>
> ```
> rate(retrieve_stripe_subscription_latency_ms_sum[5m])
> /
> rate(retrieve_stripe_subscription_latency_ms_count[5m])
> ```